# How to scale \includegraphics to exact width and height?

Tags: boxes, includegraphics, dimensions

I have an image [foo.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Felis_silvestris_silvestris.jpg).
I would like to scale it into a box of an exact size, say 100pt wide by 200pt high.
I may want to scale the axes independently, or I may want to preserve the aspect ratio and fill the shorter dimension with spaces.

However, if I use `\includegraphics[width=100pt,height=200pt]{foo.jpg}`, the resulting box is not exactly 100pt by 200pt—it's 99.9974pt by 199.99854pt.

**How can I include the graphics into a box of exactly a prescribed width and height?**

Is there a better way than creating a vbox and hbox around the includegraphics surrounded by vfil/hfil?

Or, is it possible that \includegraphics will *exceed* the prescribed width and height, requiring the use of vss/hss?

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\badbox}
\newsavebox{\goodbox}
\newlength{\mywidth} \setlength{\mywidth}{100pt}
\newlength{\myheight} \setlength{\myheight}{200pt}

\begin{document}
\typeout{mywidth=\the\mywidth, myheight=\the\myheight}%
\sbox{\badbox}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth,height=\myheight]
    {foo.jpg}}%
\sbox{\goodbox}{%
  \vbox to\myheight{%
    \vfil%
    \hbox to\mywidth{\hfil\usebox{\badbox}\hfil}%
    \vfil}}%
\typeout{badbox wd=\the\wd\badbox, ht=\the\ht\badbox, dp=\the\dp\badbox}%
\typeout{goodbox wd=\the\wd\goodbox, ht=\the\ht\goodbox, dp=\the\dp\goodbox}%
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
mywidth=100.0pt, myheight=200.0pt
badbox wd=99.9974pt, ht=199.99854pt, dp=0.0pt
goodbox wd=100.0pt, ht=200.0pt, dp=0.0pt
```

Output with `keepaspectratio`:

```
mywidth=100.0pt, myheight=200.0pt
badbox wd=99.9974pt, ht=115.57187pt, dp=0.0pt
goodbox wd=100.0pt, ht=200.0pt, dp=0.0pt
```

Comment: Welcome. TeX arithmetic is not entirely accurate. Is there some particular reason the image must be scaled so precisely? Surely there will be no visible difference between 99.98...pt and 100pt?

Comment: Can you reproduce using an image other people have? e.g. `example-image`? (See the `mwe` package for a selection.) If that's not possible, can you replace `foo.jpg` by a box? Or provide the image somewhere?

Comment: @cfr Why scale exactly: The difference may not be visually perceptible in the typeset output (which is why I think the vfil/hfil or vss/hss approach will suffice), but it may affect the sizing of surrounding boxes leading to spurious underfull or overfull box warnings, or it may incorrectly push some box onto another line.  Example image: Changed the MWE to use the first JPEG I found on Wikipedia.

Comment: You can literally use `example-image` and people won't have to download anything. I admit the image may be considered a trifle dull, but it works.

Comment: If I put the image unscaled into a coffin and resize the coffin, I don't get the inaccuracy. (But I'm not saying this would avoid the issue entirely - as far as I know, it cannot be avoided entirely.) Note that your filling approach won't work when the inaccuracy goes the other way and the dimensions are a littler larger than requested.

Comment: The only precise measurements in TeX are in units of sp and there are 65536 sp in 1 pt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to have all the nested box and glue combination you can just assert the box size

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\badbox}

\newlength{\mywidth} \setlength{\mywidth}{100pt}
\newlength{\myheight} \setlength{\myheight}{200pt}

\begin{document}
\typeout{mywidth=\the\mywidth, myheight=\the\myheight}%
\sbox{\badbox}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth,height=\myheight]
    {example-image}}%

\typeout{badbox wd=\the\wd\badbox, ht=\the\ht\badbox, dp=\the\dp\badbox}%
\ht\badbox=\myheight \wd\badbox=\mywidth
\typeout{badbox wd=\the\wd\badbox, ht=\the\ht\badbox, dp=\the\dp\badbox}%




\end{document}
```

produces

```
badbox wd=99.99736pt, ht=200.00575pt, dp=0.0pt
badbox wd=100.0pt, ht=200.0pt, dp=0.0pt
```

I did consider (a lifetime ago) making that the default behaviour but it seemed marginally better  for `height=` (and the similar `\resizebox`) to return the calculated size with the rounding error rather than the requested size.

It's done that way as most back ends can not actually set content to a specified size, only to scale. Requested size is a convenience in the user interface but it means tex has to calculate the required scale factor.

`graphicx` uses TeX dimension arithmetic which is only capable of around 5 decimal places in stored values and loses some of that in calculation, so here you see difference in the third decimal place, but 0.00264pt really isn't very big.

These days it could use more accurate (and memory intensive) calculation methods such as `l3fp` functions which use decimal floating point to much higher accuracy, around 18 significant figures, but even then you can never guarantee that *actual* x (*requested* / *actual*) exactly equals *requested* so if you type out the value as above you could get 100.0000000000001pt or some such, so you may still want to force the box to be the requested size.

---

Note if you do use glue you should use `\vss` not `\vfil` so it can shrink to negative size, note with `example-image` as above, you need to shrink the box in the vertical direction not pad it out.

---

See also https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/112

Comment: Note if you do use glue you should use `\vss` not `\vfil` so it can shrink to negative size, note with `example-image`  you need to shrink the box in the vertical direction not pad it out.

Comment: I think `l3graphics` would be on-the-money here ...

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/112

Comment: Aside from tiny potential sub-point differences in where the image might be rendered, won't assigning the width and height directly instead of surrounding with glue also affect the centering (whether vertical or horizontal) of the image in the `keepaspectratio` case?  It looks like your approach will leave the image at the bottom of the box, whereas mine will add it to the center.  (Not saying one or the other is correct—I didn't specify where I wanted it in my question—but it makes a difference.)

Comment: @TaylorRCampbell  forcing both sizes when using `keepaspectratio` is just weird, I  would never even think of offering that, it would make sense to force the direction that is used to the requested size, but then the other direction should scale by the same amount, that's the whole point.    I will add first two comments to the answer

Comment: @TaylorRCampbell  added to the answer

Comment: @TaylorRCampbell it doesn't make any practical difference, forcing the box size prevents build up of rounding error but alignment of anything anywhere is subject to the same fixed point arithmetic, if you worry about going 0.5\textwidth  (although halving is accurate) or deciding if a top float will fit or .... this arithmertic is all over. The documented baseline is the bottom edge of the image so I think just padding at the top and right is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Taking David's answer and re-coding using `l3graphics`, we get something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3graphics}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { graphics }
  {
    height .dim_set:N = \l__graphics_height_dim ,
    width .dim_set:N  = \l__graphics_width_dim ,
  }
\box_new:N \l__graphics_tmp_box
\NewDocumentCommand \includegraphics { O{} m }
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
       \keys_set_known:nn { graphics } {#1}
       \hbox_set:Nn \l__graphics_tmp_box
         { \graphics_include:nn {#1} {#2} }
       \box_resize_to_wd_and_ht_plus_dp:Nnn \l__graphics_tmp_box
         \l__graphics_width_dim \l__graphics_height_dim
       \box_use:N \l__graphics_tmp_box
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newsavebox{\badbox}

\newlength{\mywidth} \setlength{\mywidth}{100pt}
\newlength{\myheight} \setlength{\myheight}{200pt}

\begin{document}
\typeout{mywidth=\the\mywidth, myheight=\the\myheight}%
\sbox{\badbox}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth,height=\myheight]
    {example-image.pdf}}%

\typeout{badbox wd=\the\wd\badbox, ht=\the\ht\badbox, dp=\the\dp\badbox}%
\ht\badbox=\myheight \wd\badbox=\mywidth
\typeout{badbox wd=\the\wd\badbox, ht=\the\ht\badbox, dp=\the\dp\badbox}%




\end{document}
```

Note that at present `l3graphics` is for low-level graphics inclusion and doesn't cover resizing directly: a better interface would be needed to set up a complete replacement for `\includegraphics`.